# Jupyter import Python function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have the following folder structure

```
main/
     jupyter/
            nb.ipynb
     helper/
           text.txt
           foo/
              foo.py
```

The file foo.py contains

```
def foo():
    open("../text.txt", "r")
```

In the jupyter notebook I have

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../helper/foo")
from foo import foo

foo()
```

which gives a file not found error. What's the cleanest way of fixing that? (If possible, I'd like to keep `foo.py` unchanged.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because the path is relative to your working directory. You will need to change it using `os.chdir('../helper/foo')`.

It would be a bit better to change `foo.py` and use `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'text.txt')` as path.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I also think that the second part is actually better. Only a small typo: it should be `__file__`.

Comment: In the grander scheme you could also think about making your helper code an actual package and then load the file with `pkgresources`. — And thanks for the `__FILE__` hint, I was still in C++ mode in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to just go one level up and search there for your folder & module

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")  # just one level higher
from folder.module import function

function()
```